# Simple file versioning with Git

Tags: git

I'd like to use git to keep a simple history of changes to some text files (source but could be config files or anything - the Q isn't specific to s/w development).

I used to use RCS for this, which was as simple as having a job which ran daily, which found all my relevant text files (e.g. `cd /some/where; find . -name "*.foo" ...`) and checked them all in (something like `ci -q -mbackup -l filename`) - `ci` essentially does nothing if the file is unchanged. The old versions (or more accurately diffs from which the old versions could be reconstructed by rcs) were held in an RCS directory in the local file-system/disk.

At a later time I could run `rlog filename` to see the dates on which a file of interest had been altered and the number of lines changed. I could use `rcsdiff` to see the exact changes made, if need be. I could use co to revert changes.

I have no need for remote repos, syncing repos, working with other people, keeping logs of reasons for changes, branching, grouping files together, stamping version numbers or release numbers on groups of files or any other thing than basic file versioning (without using Windows 10's built in features which talks about needing an external disk and which I am suspicious of on portability grounds).

I already have git installed on Windows 10 (because golang uses git to fetch libraries etc, I don't use git directly myself) so ...

Is there a *simple* way to use git in a similar simplistic fashion?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You'll need some kind of script that cd's into `/some/where`, and then runs something along the lines of

```
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
```

Then you can use `git log $filename` to see it's history. `git log` won't show you the numbers changed, but you could script the generation of your commit message to reflect that. And `git diff` to show you the exact changes and `git revert` to revert.

Answer (score 1):

Covering some simple equivalents of the items in your question, and assuming that you have all files of interest under `/some/where`

One time initialization:

```
cd /some/where
git init
```

Commit all `foo` files changed since the last commit:

```
cd /some/where
git add "*.foo"
git commit -m "commit message about today's foo files"
```

List most recent three commits of a particular file, with summary stats:

```
cd /some/where/else
git log -3 --shortstat alphabet.foo
```

Given two commit hashes from the `git log` output, see the diff between them

```
cd /some/where/else
git diff ac132f..be8d5e alphabet.foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps wrong tool... git is for handling collections of files that change in some coordinated way. Check out another one-file-at-a-time VCS, [SRC](https://gitlab.com/esr/src). Very much new, this is meant to (somewhat) work with git, it uses the same fast-import/fast-export formats, and (re)uses some of git's global or user configuration. Even uses RCS format internally ;-)

Comment: Thanks, since SRC is by [Eric S. Raymond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond) it is of extra interest.